# Why does the Explorer.exe process stop responding/hang/crash despite no shell extension being problematic?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, windows-explorer

Please do not answer this question. I already have the answer and want to make this a PSA because I have tried all the recommendations that I have found on this site and other sites and they did not help (tracing down something in the shell etc.). Then, I finally found out what it was (see below).

Comment: Could you please edit your question into a *real* question phrased in a way that might help other people with similar problems find it.

Comment: Per [this blog entry](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) and our [FAQ], and as @Nifle said, please be as specific as possible with your question. Describe what exactly the problem is, what recommendations you've tried, what you traced down et cetera.

Comment: @WuschelbeutelKartoffelhuhn - If you had actually asked a question I would have given this question an upvote.  I suggest you reword the question to better fit this website.

Answer (score 1):

I simply had too many files on my desktop. Moving the files into another directory immediately resolved the issue and then when I started accumulating files on the desktop again, the issue creeped up again, I moved the files, and the issue disappeared again.

I have observed this both in Windows XP and Windows 7.

Comment: How many files did you have on the desktop?

Comment: Approximately 1000-2500.